# How can I set connection_limit and pool_timeout in my connectionstring when my database is MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, connection-string, prisma

I'm using `Prisma.js` in my project as an ORM.
I want to apply `connection_limit` and `pool_timeout` parameters in my `connectionstring`.

I tested these connectionstrings but they didn't work.

```
"mysql://root@localhost:3306/gamma_db&connection_limit=40&pool_timeout=20"

"mysql://root@localhost:3306/gamma_db?connection_limit=40?pool_timeout=20"
```

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the connection string must follow the pattern:

```
mysql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DATABASE?KEY1=VALUE&KEY2=VALUE&KEY3=VALUE
```

where "?" separates the *base URL* from the *Arguments* and "&" separates the actual arguments you might have.

In your case your connection string should be:

```
"mysql://root@localhost:3306/gamma_db?connection_limit=40&pool_timeout=20"
```

More examples and additional info can be found here:
[Prisma - Databased Connectors - MySQL](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mysql#arguments)

Comment: Thanks!
In terms of performance, do you know which numbers are suitable for connectionstring?

Comment: Are you running your application on Serverless?